# React native Pull to refresh is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I m trying to add pull to refresh to fetch my data from my api but it is not working and i can'y find the problem within the code:

```js
 const[refresh,setRefresh]=useState(true)

  const onRefresh=()=>{
    try{
      axios
      .get('http://192.168.1.17:8000/File/')
      .then((response)=> {
         
          setFile(response.data);
          setFilteredFile(response.data)
          setEmpty(false)
          setRefresh(false);
  
  
      })}
      catch(error){console.log(error)          
      }
  }
```

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    onRefresh()      
  },[])
```

```js
  <FlatList style={DocumentStyle.flatstyle}
              keyExtractor={(item)=>item['id']}
              data={filteredfile}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              onRefresh={()=>onRefresh()}
              refreshing={refresh}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind me everyone, i haven't set my refresh back to true after the useEffect set it to false

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to not importing useState, but you also need to import useEffect. I also dont see where some of the props your passing to FlatList are being used. But here's a working sample:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const FlatList = ({file, refreshing, onRefresh}) => {
return (
  <div>
    <p>{file}</p>
    <button onClick={() => onRefresh(2)}>Load another todo</button>
  </div>
 )
}

export default function App() {
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(true);
const [file, setFile] = useState('');

useEffect(() => onRefresh(), []);

const onRefresh = (id=1) => {
 try {
   fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json =>  {
     console.log(json)
     setFile(JSON.stringify(json))
     setRefresh(false);
   })
 }
 catch(error) {
   console.log(error);         
 }
}

  return <FlatList file={file} refreshing={refresh} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
}
```

Comment: i did import them i just didn't include the lines in the post, the error is that in my use effect i've set the refresh to false and never back to true that's why it wasn't working when i pulled.